# How to install Matplotlib in Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, numpy, matplotlib

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html#installing-from-source) tell us that the requirement is Python 2.4 or later but not Python3.

Now I'm working with Python3 and I need some plot from Matplotlib.

So how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but at the current time it's not supported.
If you feel brave, you can try with the [Py3k SVN branch](http://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matplotlib/branches/py3k/) which reportedly works with a simple example. Be aware that there has been no update in the last 8 months on this though.
Of course, you'd be more than welcome to contribute to the porting to Python 3 if you could.

Comment: The main matplotlib python3 branch is at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-py3, not the sourceforge svn branch (which is why the svn branch appears to be dead).  Also, see this wiki on the current status of matplotlib on python3 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-py3/wiki

Comment: For future readers, note that Python 3 support has now been merged into the development version of matplotlib, so it's available in the main repo: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

You could try the unofficial versions. Check this site:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs at the link it says the following is a dependency:

Python (>= 2.7 or >= 3.4)

You can download a version of Python that will work at:

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

I would go with the most recent release and a 64 bit version as certain libraries for data analysis do not run on the 32 bit version of Python.

The version of Python you download will come with `pip` which you can then use to install any libraries you need to do your work.

Make sure you have set your environment variables if you want to run your programs from the command line or bash terminal.

I installed matplotlib through the bash terminal with:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In ***Visual Studio 2022*** just use the "**Solution Explorer**" to install ***Matplotlib***.

- **Expand** the ***Project*** and then **expand** the "**Python Environments**"
- **Right click** on the ***Python installation*** and choose "**Manage Python Packages...**"

[image: Solution Explorer]

- **Type** "**matplotlib**" in the search field
- **Click** on "**Run command: pip install matplotlib**"

[image: Python Environment]

Now Matplotlib should be installed on the Visual Studio Python environment!

***Note** that if the chosen Python environment is:*

- *"Python 3.XX (global default)"

  Then Matplotlib will be installed on your default Visual Studio
  Python environment,*
- *NOT the (global default)

  Then Matplotlib will JUST be installed on your current project.*

Answer (score 0):

To install matplotlib on windows, first, you have to install pip first to install pip on windows go to website

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip

Download get-pip.py, being careful to save it as a .py file rather than .txt. Then, run it from the command prompt:

```
python get-pip.py
```

if pip is already installed, install matplotlib by writing in command prompt:

```
python -mpip install -U pip
python -mpip install -U matplotlib
```